# Setting variables equal to each other when separate arrays are equal in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, data-manipulation

I'm wondering if there's a way in Python to set two arrays equal to each other when other arrays are the same in a single line (or in an efficient way) as can be done in Matlab.

For example, say I have arrays two arrays of temperatures and two arrays of corresponding latitudes as shown below. I want to replace the temperatures in the first array (temps1) with the temperatures in the second array (temps2) where the latitudes were the same. (spacing is just to show which values correspond to which points for clarity)

```
temps1 = [20, 23, 24, 20, 25, 36, 21, 10, 32, 27]
temps2 = [        25, 21,         22, 09]

lats1  = [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 52, 53] 
lats2  = [        47, 48,         51, 52]
```

I know in Matlab, this could easily be done by simply saying

```
temps1(lats1 == lats2) = temps2;
```

is there a way in python I can do this without going through a for loop? In my actual project, I have a lot of data to go through and I would like to be more efficient if possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To clarify, are the lists `temps1` and `temps2` of the same length or no?

Comment: No, they are different sizes and different shapes.

Comment: What makes you think `temps1(lats1 == lats2) = temps2;` would have worked in Matlab? `lats1` and `lats2` don't have compatible shapes. Matlab won't line the elements up for you like you seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'd recomend using the `numpy` library. This is a very popular numeric library for python that functions much like Matlab arrays do.

In it, you would create `np` arrays from your current arrays:

```
temps1 = np.array(temps1)
```

Then, you could do what I assume you meant,

```
temps1[lats1 == lats2] = temp2[lats1 == lats2]
```

EDIT: If the arrays do not directly correspond to each other and are not equal in shape, then this would not work as is. A more complex query would be required, but more information is needed to build that.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, utilizing both `pd.Series()` and `numpy`:

```
temps1.update(lats1.map(dict(zip(lats2,temps2))).dropna())
```

This requires that `temps1` and `lats1` are both `pd.Series()`. Recasting as a list:

```
temps1.tolist()
```

Yields:

```
[20, 23, 25, 21, 25, 36, 22, 9, 9, 27]
```

Note that this solution will replace all values in `temps1` with the values in `temps2` where there exist matching values between `lats1` and `lats2`. Therefore, both occurrences of `52` will be candidates for replacement.